# JQuery selector - how to compare two element IDs

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have multiple input elements that are very similar in look and feel. The only difference is each input will have a different type of input code (Hotel vendor codes or Car vendor codes). Instead of duplicating autocomplete JavaScript code, I would like to re-use the same code for each input element but I need a way to identify which input is currently in focus so that the return values are the correct codes. Below is the the basic concept. How would I structure the if condition to know if my current input in focus is "vendor-car" or "vendor-hotel"?

**HTML:**

```html
<label>Hotel Vendor Codes</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control vendor-autocomplete vendor-hotel" id="Vendor_hotel" />

<label>Car Vendor Codes</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control vendor-autocomplete vendor-car" id="Vendor_car" />
```

**TypeScript:**

```
var vendorAutocompletes = $('.vendor-autocomplete');
var vendorCar = $('.vendor-car');

if (vendorAutocompletes.length > 0) {
    vendorAutocompletes
        .autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {

                if ($(this).attr("id") == vendorCar.attr("id")) {
                    console.log('This input is Car Vendors');
                    getVendors(request.term, VendorTypes.Car, response);
                } else {
                    console.log('This input is Hotel Vendors');
                    getVendors(request.term, VendorTypes.Hotel, response);
                }
            }

        });
}
```

Trying to determine if the event associated with the current input DOM element is of type "vendor-car" or "vendor-hotel". Instead of the current element, `$(this).attr("id")` is undefined.

```
if ($(this).attr("id") == vendorCar.attr("id")) {
```

Comment: "this" doesn't have (in your case) any id, only classes. You could check through [Element.classList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) which classes it has. You also don't need to compare it with anything, just use it as it is. (i.e. - remove the irrelevant classes from the list, then simply use that string in your getVendors call's 2nd paramenter, and in the console.log). Or add an id... whatever works for you

Comment: Looks like this works:

https://api.jquery.com/focus-selector/

`
```
    if (vendorCar.is(":focus")) {
```
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like this works:
Reference: api.jquery.com/focus-selector

```
if (vendorCar.is(":focus"))
    console.log("Input is Car Vendors");
```

Answer (score 0):

It's been a while since I don't work with jQuery, but I'll do:

```js
const vendors = $('.vendor-autocomplete')

for (const vendor of vendors) {
  switch (vendor.attr('data-vendor')) {
  case 'hotel':
    //do stuff
    break
  case 'car':
    // do some other stuff
    break
  default:
    // just in case
    break
  }
}
```

```html
<label>Hotel Vendor Codes</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control vendor-autocomplete" data-vendor="hotel" />

<label>Car Vendor Codes</label>
<input type="text" class="form-control vendor-autocomplete" data-vendor="car" />
```

If this is your only use case, I don't think you require the `id` attr for that. Just use the same class for all the inputs and store the vendor type in a custom `data` attr.

Answer (score 0):

The issue is `$(this)` is undefined.
But using an `.each()` loop would provide you the `element` that you need.

```
var vendorAutocompletes = $('.vendor-autocomplete');
var vendorCar = $('.vendor-car');

if (vendorAutocompletes.length > 0) {
    vendorAutocompletes.each(function(index, element) {
        $(element).autocomplete({
            source: function (request, response) {

                if ($(element).attr("id") == vendorCar.attr("id")) {
                    console.log('This input is Car Vendors');
                    return getVendors(request.term, VendorTypes.Car, response);
                } else {
                    console.log('This input is Hotel Vendors');
                    return getVendors(request.term, VendorTypes.Hotel, response);
                }
            }

        });
    })
}
```

I added the possibly missing `return`...